# 70s science fiction book, with two warring planetary super computers

Tags: story-identification, books

Planetary computers, one male the other female, the female supercomputer was named Jermaine. Different planets, Jermaine was one planet and the male counterpart was another planet. After they warred, humanity was reduced to living in caves and almost extinct. Two interplanetary leonine humanoids, a couple, discover the cave dwelling humans, learn of the war, and that it was a lovers spat between two worlds.

This book was from the 70s

Comment: Jermaine was one, was Brett the other?

Comment: The theme reminds of *Firebird* (where the aliens were felinoids, not leonoids, and the computers were called Largo (male) and Czandra (female).

Comment: Yes ! Thank you, Firebird by Charles L Harness was the book.

Comment: @JamesfromNZ - The name of the male supercomputer isn't germane :-)

Answer (score 6):

Per the OP comment above, this was [Firebird](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1947) by Charles L. Harness, published 1980 or 1981 (isfdb and goodreads disagree).

Summary from [the Amazon Kindle entry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014Q0W3FO):

> From the distant dipoles of the universe, two telepathic computers, Largo and Czandra, known as Control, rule over life on all civilized planets. And now, with Project Cancelar, Control has formulated a plan for achieving immortality...a plan which requires as fodder the collapsing of the universe and the destruction of all life. And there is nothing the humans can do.
>
> But there is another force in the universe, hidden in the abyss of the Silent Quarter...plotting destruction of Control. A force that is about to be demolished! Before it expires, it launches from its depths a magic ring, an elixir, and a man and a woman in love - riding within the living spirit of a remarkable spaceship to do battle against the cumulative technology of the entire universe.